# python-django file upload 'key error'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.2, django-1.6

I am using python 3.2 & django 1.6. I want to upload to upload a 'csv' file and read data inorder to insert it into database(postgresql).  Here is my code
Template

```
<form id = "ListForm" name = "ListForm" action = "" method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>PM List</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file_pm" id="file_pm" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="pmUpload" id="pmUpload" class="button"></td></tr>       
</table>
</form>
```

Python code is:

```
import cgi
def pmUpload(request):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    fileitem = form["file_pm"]
```

I got 'KeyError' in the lastline of the above python code.I was trying to read data one by one.

And the full traceback error is

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://MYURL/cc/pmList/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 3.2.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ccApp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/env/ccENV/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/env/ccENV/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/env/ccENV/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/env/cccENV/ccc/ccApp/pmList.py" in pmUpload
  19.       fileitem = form["file_pm"]
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/cgi.py" in __getitem__
  575.             raise KeyError(key)

Exception Type: KeyError at /cc/pmList/
Exception Value: 'file_pm'
```

How to read data in python 3.2 from the uploaded file(data.csv)

Comment: where does the error come from?  (we need to see the error, and the full traceback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be in `request.FILES['file_pm']`.

Comment: Do u know how to read each column from the uploaded csv file. I tried the 'for' loop but its getting as a row like this  b'1566|PR/1869|LSR|710|2013-05-20|3|GP2|PC/3850\n'

Comment: I'd recommend using [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).